# How to reset resolution and "set custom scaling level" in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, resolution

I'm using a DELL PRECISION M4400 workstation. I messed up the screen resolution of my Windows-10 installation by adjusting the *set custom scaling level* and the *screen resolution* one after the other.

I looked up online for ways to reset them (bring both of them to defaults) in vain. This question *[Monitor reset itself and now I can't set the resolution/settings back to how it was before](https://superuser.com/questions/447977/monitor-reset-itself-and-now-i-cant-set-the-resolution-settings-back-to-how-it)* seems to address a monitor issue and not ways of bringing the resolution / custom scaling back.

The impact is not just on Windows, but also on my VMs.  For example, my Mac OSX looks like a small box even VMplayer is running full screen.

[image].

Is there an easier way to reset these settings?

- My current resolution is 1920 X 1200
- Scaling is at 150%

If there is no other option - I should think of re-installing my Windows-10.

Comment: "by adjusting the set custom scaling level and the screen resolution one after." - Can't you just simply set it back to the default values?  I am not entirely clear, on what you actually did, the sentence appears to be an incomplete statement.

Comment: @Ramhound.... "the other" got deleted by mistake. I have updated the question now. The problem with *set custom scaling* is it will work at the present resolution level. X% of current resolution. And when u change the resolution and again change *custom scaling* - it is a function of past scaling + present scaling (at new resolution)... It is complex

Comment: **Close votes** can make someone think harder of the problem... I re-visited the problem and now it is solved.... Thanks Community!

Comment: Be sure you submit an answer to your question so you help all those with the same problem.

Comment: The answer is simply *stupid*. I tried visiting all the resolutions until I got the one that best fitted me without any scaling (0%). To my surprise, this approach was not given in any of the online portals. But the sharpness of the text is gone now... I can live with that